# conditional operator can return reference?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I came across a line of code and never thought it might work well. I thought the conditional operator return value and does not work with reference.

Some pseudo code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A(int input) : v(input) {};
  void print() const { cout << "print: " << v  << " @ " << this << endl; }
  int v;
private:
  //A A(const A&);
  //A operator=(const A&);
};

class C {
public:
  C(int in1, int in2): a(in1), b(in2) {}
  const A& getA() { return a;}
  const A& getB() { return b;}
  A a;
  A b;
};

int main() {
  bool test = false;
  C c(1,2);
  cout << "A @ " << &(c.getA()) << endl;
  cout << "B @ " << &(c.getB()) << endl;

  (test ? c.getA() : c.getB()).print();  // its working
}
```

Can someone explain? Thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your assumption about the conditional operator is wrong. The type of the expression is whatever type the expressions `c.getA()` and `c.getB()` have, if they have the same type, and if they denote lvalues, then so does the entire expression. (The exact rules are in §5.16 of the C++ standard.)

You can even do this:

```
(condition? a: b) = value;
```

to conditionally set either `a` or `b` to `value`. Note that this is C++-specific; in C, the conditional operator does not denote an lvalue.